# Document Stream snapshot.hasData returns true but no data, how to fix this?

Tags: firebase, stream, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am streaming a Document snapshot from Firestore, but snapshot.hasData returns true when there is nothing in the db. This causes my code to fail when try retrieve value out of the snapshot.

How do I fix this?

I tried print out snapshot.Data just got an Documentsnapshot instance. Also thought about provide initial data to the stream, but I do not know how to provide an empty DocumentSnapshot data type.

If I manually insert a record in to firestore, it works fine.

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(

          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('UserDetails').document(widget.uid).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){

            if(snapshot.hasError){
              widget._err = snapshot.error;
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              widget._loadingUserInfo = true;
            } else if (snapshot.hasData){
              nameController.text = snapshot.data['name'];
              ageController.text = snapshot.data['age'];
              introController.text = snapshot.data['intro'];
              widget._loadingUserInfo = false;
            }
)
```

I am trying to get user value from Firestore to populate their form if there is a value or user exists.

Now it just fails.

Comment: You are not returning anything to `builder: (context, snapshot)` ?

Comment: Return are not shown here, it’s a pretty long widget. But I don’t think it will affect anything tho :/

Answer (score 6):

I've found that although `print( snapshot.hasData );` gets true, 
`print( snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty );` and `print( snapshot.data.exists );` get true as well..

hence, to solve my issue, I used:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) //for QuerySnapshot
```

OR

```
if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data.exists) //for DocumentSnapshot
```

Answer (score 1):

`snapshot.hasData` will return true **for an empty dataset**, ie:

`snapshot.data = []`

Personally, I consider `hasData` to mean "has a response".

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the confusion is that Firestore returns a `DocumentSnapshot` even when there is nothing in the database to return.

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: firestore
        .document('collection/non_existant_document')
        .get(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        print('Has Data');
      }
    }),
```

The above code returns an empty `DocumentSnapshot`. However, since it returns `DocumentSnapshot` in `data`, `hasData` evaluates to true.

To check if the `DocumentSnapshot` contains data, use

```
if (snapshot.data?.exists ?? false) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for `hasData` to return `true` when there no data.

`hasData` is nothing but a shorthand for:

```
snapshot.data != null
```

Which means that you *do* have data. But maybe not the data you want.

Comment: when I print( snapshot.hasData ); I get false then another true followed up, maybe it is the streaming? My db is completely empty.

Comment: I am in the same situation. hasData is true but there is no data. The solution to check if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data.exists) has worked for me

Comment: `hasData` returns true even if the document does not exist in the database. Even when `snapshot.data == null`, `hasData` returns true.

Comment: Under what circumstances would you consider an empty list to mean a list with data?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a validation?

Something like

```
if (snapshot.hasData && (snapshot.data == null) return SizedBox();
```

Also if you are retrieving a list you could check if `data != null and snapshot.data.length == 0;`

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try checking if data is null with:
`if (snapshot.data == '[]') then`

In your case...

```
....
else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.toString() != '[]') then){
   nameController.text = snapshot.data['name'];
   ageController.text = snapshot.data['age'];
   introController.text = snapshot.data['intro'];
   widget._loadingUserInfo = false;
}
```

Took me an hour to figure this out...